# How to generate keys and aggregate groupby function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have tables like this,

I must build pipelines like

① generate new key `E=B or C`.

② separate each customer by `group` key

③ groupby through aggregate function like `count`,`sum`

I can imagine each process,but I confused to composite each steps.

```
customer group score
A         1     10
B         2     20
C         1     10
B         1     10
C         2     10
D         2     10
```

My desired result is like this.

```
customer  count(1)  count(2) avg(1) avg(2)
A           1         0        10     0
D           0         1        0      10
E           2         2        10     15
```

If you have any opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in your sample data is called `key`, so I see no relationship between the sample data and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  case when customer in ('B', 'C') then 'E' else customer end customer,
  count(case when `group` = 1 then 1 end),
  count(case when `group` = 2 then 1 end),
  coalesce(avg(case when `group` = 1 then score end), 0),
  coalesce(avg(case when `group` = 2 then score end), 0)
from tablename
group by case when customer in ('B', 'C') then 'E' else customer end
```

Replace the backticks around `group` with double quotes or square brackets to work with your database because `group` is a reserved word.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c8cfcQEQfKjD1m5kSmWWHV/1).